# Multiple Restcomm USSD Gateways behind a load balancer

Tags: cluster-computing, load-balancing, gateway, ussd, restcomm

Does anyone know how to arrange Multiple Restcomm USSD GateWay nodes in a cluster?
Is there some sort of documentation or examples? I didn't find no one.

Thanks in advance.